How to redirect the fzf matching output to a file?
I am using fzf with etcdctlv3 keys and then dynamically searching for some prefix in fzf and getting some matches with the keys. Now I want to save the matches into a file. How can I a do that? The command that I am using is
etcdctlv3 get --prefix "/" | fzf

